# lambda search in combined string

Tags: c#, string, lambda, contain

Here is my table data ,

```
 Areas                           Cities
==============================================================
Area1                   City1 , City2 , City3 , City4
Area2                   City5 , City6 , City7 , City8
Area3                   City9 , City10 , City11 , City12
Area4                   City13 , City14 , City15 , City16
```

If I give the value `City1` , I want to get `Area1` .
(eg. City7 => Area2 , City14 => Area4) .
Is there any short way to do it using **Lambra Expression** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
yourDataTable.First(x => x.Cities.Split(',').Any(y => y.Trim() == "City1"))
```

Where search term is string like `City 1`

Comment: Using `x.Cities.Split(',').Contains(SearchTerm)` would be a bit simpler.

Comment: It give me the error message `Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.String[]'.` !

Comment: Edited to previous version with Damith tip to use trim

Comment: try converting the variable of string[] to List<string>, It should solve your error.

Answer (score 2):

if you need exact match, try

```
var rec = tbl.ToList().FistOrDefault(x => x.Cities.Split(',')
                                  .Any(City => City == SearchTerm));
```

`Contains` will give wrong results, since if you search `City1` it will match even `City11`

**Note:**

since you have space before the `,` you need to call `Trim` method to get the word and also if you need do a case intensive search do as below

```
var rec = tbl.ToList().FistOrDefault(x => x.Cities.Split(',')
                                  .Any(City => City.Trim().Equals(SearchTerm, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: It give me the error message `Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.String[]'.` !